# How do I fill a bar plot with a specific colour palette according to the variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, geom-bar, pallet

Trying to assing each variable colour by creating my own colour palette, but some of the colours get mixed up. Any ideas on how I should fix this?

```
cor.partidos <- c(
  `ps` = "#f71b75",
  `psd` = "#ef6438",
  `pcp-pev` = "#ff001d",
  `pan` = "#71af64",
  `outros` = "#f71b75",
  `nulos` = "#565557",
  `brancos` = "#aaa8ad",
  `l` = "#f71b75",
  `il` = "#f71b75",
  `ch` = "#393195",
  `cds-pp` = "#1192d8",
  `be` = "#b40020",
  `a` = "#f71b75") 

#test graph
bars <- ggplot(leg19, aes(x = partido, y = votos)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", 
           position="identity", 
           fill = cor.partidos) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, size = 1, colour="#333333") +
  bbc_style() +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=10))+
  labs(subtitle = "Resultados Legislativas 2019",
       ylab = "votos")
```

[image: bars]

**update with a mwe**

It will work if the variables in the pallet are in the same order as the dataframe but if you mix it around a bit it won't work. Changing it to `aes(fill = cor.partidos)` won't work :(

```
test.pallet <- c(
  `pink` = "#f71b75",
  `orange` = "#ef6438",
  `green` = "#71af64",
  `red` = "#ff001d",
  `other pink` = "#f71b72")

test.datafrane <- data_frame(
  name = c("pink","orange","red","green","other pink"),
  value = c(1,2,3,4,5)
)
test.datafrane$value <- as.numeric(test.datafrane$value)

test.graph <- ggplot(test.datafrane, aes(x = name, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", 
           position="identity", 
           fill = test.pallet)
test.graph
```

[image: test.graph]

[image: test.graph with aes(fill = test.pallet)]

Comment: does changing `fill = cor.partidos` to `aes(fill = cor.partidos)` fix the problem?  If not, could we please have a [mre] ... ???

Comment: I would try with `aes(..., fill = partido)`. To make use of your custom color palette try with `+ scale_fill_manual(values = cor.partidos)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in my comment you could achieve your result by mapping your categorical var on `fill` inside aes() and make use of `scale_fill_manual`:

```r
test.pallet <- c(
  `pink` = "#f71b75",
  `orange` = "#ef6438",
  `green` = "#71af64",
  `red` = "#ff001d",
  `other pink` = "#f71b72")

test.datafrane <- data.frame(
  name = c("pink","orange","red","green","other pink"),
  value = c(1,2,3,4,5)
)
test.datafrane$value <- as.numeric(test.datafrane$value)

library(ggplot2)

test.graph <- ggplot(test.datafrane, aes(x = name, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", 
           position="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = test.pallet)
test.graph
```

[image]